# Automatic semantic versioning of code

Tags: version-control, semantic-versioning

I am trying to implement versioning in my project. Requirement is to implement automatic semantic versioning(ex- 1.0.1). Just wanted to know, is there any way to implement semantic versioning automatically or we have to give semantic versions manually?

I am trying to save Json schemas in database with semantic versioning. So i am looking for implementing versioning at server side our at database level.
I have already used Hibernate envers to implement automatic versioning in form of 0,1,2.

Is there any other similar versioning technique which we can implement for automatic versioning?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking JavaScript then you could try [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release). It's a powerful system for automated package publishing that updates version numbers in your package.json based on git commit messages.

Comment: I am trying to save Json schemas in database with semantic versioning. So i am looking for implementing versioning at server side our at database level.

Comment: I have created a program that accomplishes the same thing for automatic semantic versioning plus includes many more features. See https://github.com/GetchaDEAGLE/eagle-versioner.